# no return when overriding OrientationEventListener

Tags: android, listener, sensormanager

This is the problematic code :

```
    m_myOrientationEventListener
    = new OrientationEventListener(getApplicationContext(),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL){
        @Override
         public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Orientation changed !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    };
```

Everything worked before i added this code , after adding, i see a "blank" layout on the emulator

As i was able to see from the debug, the function (OrientationEventListener) is called twice ...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: After searching a bit more i noticed there is a relevant bug with the emulator and this method ?